# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I get this error when Ii execute runserver and I try to access the API:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: ''
```

I check imports, models, serializer, viewsets and URLs. I don't know what does it means?

Here you have a screenshot of the error:

[image: API]
I get that exception when I go to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/notes/`

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1.0/notes/

Django Version: 2.2.4
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'note',
 'rest_framework']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']

The traceback is:

    Traceback:

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
      34.             response = get_response(request)

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
      143.                 response = response.render()

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
      106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\response.py" in rendered_content
      70.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py" in render
      725.         context = self.get_context(data, accepted_media_type, renderer_context)

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py" in get_context
      656.         raw_data_post_form = self.get_raw_data_form(data, view, 'POST', request)

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\renderers.py" in get_raw_data_form
      564.                 data = serializer.data.copy()

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
      559.         ret = super().data

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in data
      265.                 self._data = self.get_initial()

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in get_initial
      409.             for field in self.fields.values()

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py" in __get__
      80.         res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in fields
      360.         for key, value in self.get_fields().items():

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py" in get_fields
      1056.             fields[field_name] = field_class(**field_kwargs)

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\fields.py" in __init__
      1503.             allow_folders=allow_folders, required=required

    File "C:\Users\lrond\Desktop\projectEnreda\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\fields.py" in __init__
      1109.             for f in os.scandir(self.path):

    Exception Type: FileNotFoundError at /api/v1.0/notes/
    Exception Value: [WinError 3] El sistema no puede encontrar la ruta especificada: ''
```

serializer.py

```
from .models import Note
from rest_framework import serializers

class NoteSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Note
        fields  = '__all__'
```

viewsets.py

```
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .models import Note
from .serializer import NoteSerializer

class NoteViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Note.objects.all()
    serializer_class = NoteSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework import routers

from .viewsets import NoteViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register('notes', NoteViewSet)

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem was in models.py, I have a FilePathField.

Thanks @IşıkKaplan

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Note(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    endDate = models.DateTimeField()
    note = models.TextField()
    attachment = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    task = models.BooleanField()
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```